# Inbound mail to SES fails with authentication failure

Tags: amazon-ses

I use SES for transactional email quite often. Recently Amazon announced inbound email to SES and I'd like to receive a message and just have it forward to an SNS topic.

The setup is straight forward and I've followed the developer guide and everything seems to be set up correctly. I have an MX record for my subdomain I want this to work under and my domain is verified.

Except it doesn't work. If I try to send a message to my SES recipient. The MX record / domain is found but the mail bounces back to me with the error "530 Authentication Failure"

I've been searching google and the developer forums for hours now and I can't seem to find anyone else with this problem. I suspect there's something misconfigured but I don't see anywhere I can receive a better error message.

Comment: What did AWS support say?

Comment: What is the SES hostname in your MX record, and which SES region did you configure the service in?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - that's the problem. I have the MX pointed to the "normal" SMTP host instead of the "inbound" host. I feel dumb now. Thanks!

Comment: That seemed like the most likely explanation, since they're different hostnames in each direction.  Would you like to delete the question, or do you think it would be potentially helpful to future visitors for me to post an answer to it?

Comment: Post an answer and I'll upvote you. Maybe it will help someone since its kind of buried in Amazon's docs.